# type of ref and mouseEvent reactTypscript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a navbar that i want to hide when we click outside that sidenav.
I found an interessting code that helps me to do so, however to implement it in typscript i have to use the right types.

This code uses useRef and an event listener on the document

```
function OutsideClick(ref) {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(e: MouseEvent) {
      console.log(ref)
      console.log(e.clientX)
       if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e)) {
         setIsClicked(true)
       } else {
         setIsClicked(false)
       }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    }
  }, [ref])
  return isClicked
}
//sidebar
interface sidebarState {
  isSideBarOpen: boolean
}
export default function Sidebar({ isSideBarOpen }: sidebarState) {
  const displayValue = isSideBarOpen ? 'translateX(0px)' : 'translateX(500px)'
  const navRef = useRef(null)
  const boxOutsideClick = OutsideClick(navRef)

  return (
    <nav ref={navRef} className={styles.sidebar} style={{ transform: displayValue }}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link href='/'>Accueil</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    )
}
```

My question is: what type do i need to use for the parameter ref in outsideClick and then what type should i use to access things like e.path or e.target.someOtherProperties on the mousedown listener fo the document.

For the ref i tried 'MutableRefObject' but it doesnt work, it says :Cannot find name 'MutableRefObject'.

Answer (score 2):

use `HTMLElement` type

```
const navRef = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null)
```

for `OutsideClick` use `MutableRefObject` with the type

```
import { MutableRefObject } from "react"


OutsideClick(ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>) {
```